# update Windows Form Connection string from local db for other users

Tags: c#, winforms, connection

I did review several other posts on the site and come up with the following solution, but am not having success. I placed the connection string into the app.config file and added the configuration management code to the application code. The application works fine if remove the configuration management line of code reading the connection string from the local database in the application.

app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\cvyc8\Documents\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

application code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Week_4_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\cvyc8\Documents\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        int Id = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
            var connection =
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
            ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Open();
                if (btnSave.Text == "Save")
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("MemberAddorEdit", con);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", "Add");
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 0);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", txtNumber.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Save Successful");
                }
                else
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("MemberAddorEdit", con);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", "Edit");
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", txtNumber.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Updated Successful");
                }
                Reset();
                FillDataGridView();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        void FillDataGridView()
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("MemberDisplayorSearch", con);
            sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
            DataTable dTbl = new DataTable();
            sqlDA.Fill(dTbl);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dTbl;
            con.Close();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FillDataGridView();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message");
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                txtName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txtNumber.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                txtAddress.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                btnSave.Text = "Edit";
                btnDelete.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        void Reset()
        {
            txtName.Text = txtNumber.Text = txtAddress.Text = "";
            btnSave.Text = "Save";
            Id = 0;
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Reset();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Reset();
            FillDataGridView();

        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Open();

                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("MemberDelete", con);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successful");
                Reset();
                FillDataGridView();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you get the connection string from the app.config file but you never use it to actually open a connection. Try to add `con = new SqlConnection(connection)` at the end of the `Form1` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to read the connection **string** from the configuration file in the contructor is correct. You create a **SqlConnection** with a constant string at form creation. You never feed the read connection **string** into your **SqlConnection** instance.

There are two options to rectify that: move the creation of your SqlConnection to the constructor or set the connectionstring property of your SqlConnection instance.

#### Option 1: Move the creation of the SqlConnection to the constuctor

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    readonly SqlConnection con; // readonly as we want to keep that one connection around.
    int Id = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    }
```

#### Option 2: Set the connectionString property of your SqlConnection

note that I left the SqlConnection constructor call with its value untouched here but it has no purpose anymore and it better removed. I didn't want to optimize or introduce too many changes that might confuse you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\cvyc8\Documents\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"); // this can be the default ctor.
    int Id = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

See also the  MSDN Connection for the [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8) type.

#### Option 3: Combine option 1 and 2

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // assume we create and assign an instance once
    // so mark the var readonly
    readonly SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString);
    int Id = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```